# how to do asynchronous http requests with epoll and python 3.1

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, python-3.x, nonblocking

**UPDATE: after much laboring with Py3, including writing my own asynchronous webserver (following a presentation given by Dave Beazley), i finally dumped Python (and a huge stack of my code )-: in favor of [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) running on [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). Check it out: [GitHub](https://github.com) (where you'll find like 95% of all interesting code these days), [npm](http://npmjs.org/) (package manager that couldn't be any user friendly; good riddance, `easy_install`, you never lived up to your name), an insanely huge repository of modules (with tons of new stuff being published virtually 24/7), a huge and vibrant community, out-of-the-box asynchronous HTTP and filehandling..., all that (thanks to [V8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/)) at [one third the speed of light](http://onlyjob.blogspot.com/2011/03/perl5-python-ruby-php-c-c-lua-tcl.html) — what's not to like? read more propaganda: ["The future of Scripting"](http://spreewebdesign.de/node/) (slide hosting courtesy [SpreeWebdesign](http://spreewebdesign.de)).**

there is an interesting page http://scotdoyle.com/python-epoll-howto.html about how to do asnchronous / non-blocking / AIO http serving in python 3.

there is the [tornado web server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) which does include a non-blocking http client. i have managed to port parts of the server to python 3.1, but the implementation of the client requires [pyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) and [seems to have problems](http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/276059a076593266/c49e8f834497271e?lnk=gst&q=httpclient+trouble+with+epoll#c49e8f834497271e) (with one participant stating how ‘Libcurl is such a pain in the neck’, and looking at the incredibly ugly pyCurl page i doubt pyCurl will arrive in py3+ any time soon).

now that epoll is available in the standard library, it should be possible to do asynchronous http requests out of the box with python. i really do not want to use asyncore or whatnot; epoll has a reputation for being the ideal tool for the task, and it is part of the python distribution, so using anything but epoll for non-blocking http is highly counterintuitive (prove me wrong if you feel like it).

oh, and i feel threading is horrible. no threading. i use [stackless](http://stackless.com/).

*people further interested in the topic of asynchronous http should not miss out on this [talk by peter portante at PyCon2010](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1501/pycon-2010-demystifying-non-bl); also of interest is [the keynote](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1605/pycon-2010-keynote-relentlessl), where speaker antonio rodriguez at one point emphasizes the importance of having up-to-date web technology libraries right in the standard library.*

**edit** there may be many ways to achieve high throughputs with little resource consumption. however, it is not only me who thinks that abandoning threads (and other, partially outdated, methods); the people over at the [google skipfish project](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/wiki/SkipfishDoc) seem to think similar: they say skipfish uses a

> Multiplexing single-thread, fully
>   asynchronous network I/O and data
>   processing model that eliminates
>   memory management, scheduling, and IPC
>   inefficiencies present in some
>   multi-threaded clients.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I have a library at:
  http://github.com/mnot/nbhttp/

The client side is in production as part of redbot.org.

I haven't tried it in Python 3, but it may help as a basis for your work.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

In [this poll](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-bugs-list@python.org/msg61273.html), months ago, Giampaolo Rodolá said

> I have a patch for adding epoll()
>   support which is almost ready
>   (asyncore supports poll(), not
>   epoll()), it's just a matter of
>   writing tests.

I'm not sure where to find that patch, but it seems a simple enough task that it should be readily portable into `asyncore` (the standard python library approach to async servers and clients -- sure, way behind Twisted or Tornado, but that's what the stdlib has;-).

Comment: yes, but epoll is in the standard library, too... and as some poeple have pointed out (e.g. http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/29901-asyncore-deficiencies), asyncore can be nasty. i really have set my mind on epoll...

Answer (score 0):

circuits has support for epoll and includes an async )#50 client.

http://circuitsframework.com/

Answer (score -2):

Python 3 lacks libraries. You seem interested in libraries to help you do stuff, so why exactly are you using python 3 to solve your problem?

Comment: python 3 is the future! ;-) actually, the standard library of python 3 is a little better than that of the 2.x series. language-wise, there are many improvements; among them the sane treatment of string encoding issues. with this, most encoding headaches have simply gone away! i guess that sticking to python 2 will be a widespread phenomenon, like python 1.5.x stuck a lot and internet explorer 6 stuck a lot. i am actually just building a piece of interprocess communication so i can run some stuff under python 2.6 and some stuff under 3.1... but doing it right in 3.1 would be so much better!

Comment: @flow: All string encoding improvements are backported to 2.6 so that's not much of an improvement - you can just `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and that's it! In fact most improvements have been backported, and you lose libraries, so for the meantime py3 is more of a pain than an improvement. Perhaps they'll put something to attract people on py3 in the future but the improvements are not enough to make up for the upgrade trouble yet.

Comment: python 2.x has ceased development, which means it is highly unadvisable to start any project in that branch. other than that, i recommend to move to NodeJS these days — see my pitch in the update to my question.

Comment: @flow: The fact alone that it ceased official development doesn't mean it's unadvisable to use. It is highly advisable when it solves your problem and has the things you want. I wouldn't advise something like "you have to throw write everything out and rewrite from scratch because there's a new version of the language". It seems backwards, even if the language version number is higher. In fact, version number seems to be of small importance when deciding whether something is advisable or not. That said, python 2.x development continues on the new faster implementation under the name of "pypy".